# Applying the operators on digits of number to get the desired number

Tags: java

Following is the google interview question, Can someone please solve or provide the logic to find the answer. Operators [+,-,*]

> Output should be the list of all the possible strings which generates the target number.
>
> Ex1:

```
Input = 1234

Desired number = 6
```

`Expected Output = [2+4,3+4-1,2*3,1+2+3... etc]`

> Ex2:

```
Input = 105

Desired number = 5
```

`Expected Output = [10-5,1*5... etc]`

Comment: Understand that people have the option to down vote, i accept it if you provide the answer. Anyone can down vote, can i assume that you dont know the answer that's why you people down voted?

Comment: Did you try to find answer on the special sites ?  where  developers  solve coding challenges. I found solution for this task during  2 minutes
https://leetcode.com/problems/expression-add-operators/

Comment: @ADITYAVALLURU you need to add the code to show us what u have tried. This is not the place where u will just ask for the code directly. You also need to show your efforts, what research you have done. Your question was down voted for one of [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228358/why-are-my-questions-on-stack-overflow-getting-downvotes-without-explanation), Before Asking you should go through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Have a nice day

Comment: @JennisVaishnav, I've asked for the logic or the algorithm. This is completely discouraging for the people who ask for the questions. If people dont like the question, they can ignore it or suggest a right way.

Comment: @ADITYAVALLURU That's the thing. You could have tried creating an algorithm or rather google the problem first, And then ask where you are stuck. There are some basic steps/rules to ask questions at SO, if you don't follow them, You'll have to face the consequences. -Good Day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick fix for you.

Please check following code.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
        String num = "105";
        int target = 5;
        getValue(num, target);
    }

    static void check(double sum, double previous, String digits, double target, String expr) {
        if (digits.length() == 0) {
            if (sum + previous == target) {
                System.out.println(expr + " = " + target);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 1; i <= digits.length(); i++) {
                double current = Double.parseDouble(digits.substring(0, i));
                String remaining = digits.substring(i);
                check(sum + previous, current, remaining, target, expr + " + " + current);
                check(sum, previous * current, remaining, target, expr + " * " + current);
                check(sum, previous / current, remaining, target, expr + " / " + current);
                check(sum + previous, -current, remaining, target, expr + " - " + current);
            }
        }
    }

    static void getValue(String digits, double target) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= digits.length(); i++) {
            String currentValue = digits.substring(0, i);
            check(0, Double.parseDouble(currentValue), digits.substring(i), target, currentValue);
        }
    }
```

**Output :**

1 * 0.0 + 5.0 = 5.0

1 * 5.0 = 5.0

10 - 5.0 = 5.0

Hope this example is help you to understand the concept.